# attribute class css

Tags: css

I am giving the below css rule and it is not working properly in chrome...
I am sure that it is due to order of the properties.....
I guess every focus and hover has to go in to one hover and focus..

```
.chk{
    .ico {
        background-position: -17px top;
        .stdChk;
    }

    &:hover .ico {
        background-position: -17px -34px;
    }

    &:focus .ico {
        background-position: -17px -51px;
    }

    &.disabled .ico { background-position: -17px -17px; }

    &.checked {
        .ico { background-position: left top; }

        &:hover .ico { background-position: left -34px; }

        &:focus .ico { background-position: left -51px; }

        &.disabled .ico { background-position: left -17px; }
    }
}
```

but i am quite new to this pattern, so i am not sure how to organise..any help plz...

Comment: Please post CSS code, not SASS code, if you present your problem as a CSS problem. Alternatively, specify how you are using SASS and re-title and re-tag your question.

Comment: thats what the css i am applying to element from my style sheet

Comment: This question is not answerable. It misrepresents SASS as CSS, does not identify how the code is used, does not show any relevant HTML code, and does not describe the problem (“not working properly” is not a problem description).

Answer (score 2):

That is not CSS. It's [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) code and it has to be compiled to CSS before sending to browser.

That's why it's not working in Chrome (and in any other browser).